# In Excel macro how to assign negative sign when copy paste function

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

In Excel macro how to assign negative sign when copy paste function , how to assign the negative sign for debit column when copy paste function

Comment: Have you thought/researched about it yourself?

Comment: yes, i dont know macro excel so please help me